# Python XML fast count number of elements with certain tag

Tags: python, xml, parsing, split, xml.etree

I have just started out programming in Python a while ago and I am currently working on a really big dataset. It is one xml file, the size of about 80GB, so I can't just parse it e.g. with xml.etree.ElementTree, because it simply won't fit into my RAM. (File: ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/interpro/46.0/, see match_complete.xml.gz)

What I did until now: I iterparsed it, always cleaning the current element and the root of it, as soon as I found what I was looking for, which is pretty efficient (requires less than 10MB of RAM).

What I am trying to do now, is parallelize my parsing, since I have 10 cores and 20 threads at my disposal. In order to do so, I am planning on splitting this one big xml file into 20 smaller ones, so I can just start a search in each of the small files in parallel (this might be a second question, in another thread).

Since I am not only trying to do this for one dataset, which size I can easily look up (see release_notes.txt in the upper link), but I want this to be a more general script for further use, I am looking for the most efficient way of finding out, how many elements with a certain tag are present in this huge xml file, so I can always split the files according to the number of threads I have available.

Datastructure looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE interpromatch SYSTEM "match_complete.dtd">
<interpromatch>

<release>
    <dbinfo Here is stuff I am totally not interested in>
    <dbinfo Here is stuff I am totally not interested in>
</release><protein id="A0A000" name="A0A000_9ACTN" length="394" crc64="F1DD0C1042811B48">
<match id=Some info about the proteins in my case>
  <ipr Some info I am acutally looking for, when I am parsing the file ESSENTIAL />
  <Don't need this either />
</match>
    <match id=Some info about the proteins in my case>
  <ipr Some info I am acutally looking for, when I am parsing the file ESSENTIAL />
  <Don't need this either />
</match>
<match id=Some info about the proteins in my case>
  <ipr Some info I am acutally looking for, when I am parsing the file ESSENTIAL />
  <Don't need this either />
</match>
</protein>
.
.
. (around 50000000 more entries in the whole db)
<protein>
<match id=Some info about the proteins in my case>
  <ipr Some info I am acutally looking for, when I am parsing the file ESSENTIAL />
  <Don't need this either />
</match>
</protein>
</interpromatch>
```

Let's say I am looking for the tag "protein" and my database contains 10000 entries of that kind. I want to be able to look this number up as fast as possible (iterating I think is simply not feasable), so I can find out, how many of those entries there are and divide this number by the number of threads. In this example I want to get e.g. len(tree.findall("protein")), so I know, how many of those entries I have to put into one of the smaller files. This would be 10000(proteins)/20(threads) per file in this case.

I am mainly working with Python, but I would consider everything, that just tells me, how many "protein" entries there are in my database as fast as possible.

Just for completeness sake, what I am trying to do later is:
Start a script/subprocess for each of the smaller files and query it for a certain attribute in the "ipr" section. There I am looking for a certain identifier and if this one is present, extract data from the parent "protein" node. Combine those results, and work with those.

I hope you get what I mean and can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: there is no magic bullet here... you absolutely have to iterparse one way or another, if you really want better performance you ought to look outside of python as with this much allocation/deallocation python solutions will be slow

Comment: I agree with the comment here. I struggle to see how you would achieve this WITHOUT iterating. Even if there was a built in method for it, it would probably still just iterate through everything anyway much like the `if x in y` process. You say it's not feasible but have you tried it and timed it to see whether it's acceptable? Alternatively if you know that you are going to require a similar process a lot of the time you could spend extra computation time creating some kind of index and then poll that later on. But that's basically the same. Not sure what you're expecting tbh.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's why I said, I don't really care, which programming language is the fastest here, I just want this one result and this should be doable in any programming language rather easily. I am really looking for the fastest possible method, to get this number, nothing else. Something else, I considered already, is to just split the file into really small chunks and add those back together, if I get too many chunks. But this I guess would be wasting resources even more.

Comment: It takes 6 min for 1 million sequences to be counted. Which means around 300 min for the whole dataset, which in turn means 5 hours of waiting for a number to appear. This just seems a bit too long for me.  I had hoped, that there was some kind of really fast xml parser, that can just run through the file and count items without doing to much on the side.